# Calculation view on Smart Data Access remote table

Tags: hana

I have big data that one HANA cannot hold, I want to use Smart Data Access to create a virtual table on another HANA box and build a calculation view union local table and virtual table.

Is it a viable solution? I am not sure mechanism of calculation views. It is not materialized, right?

When I do some grouping on my remote table via calculation view, raw data does not pass through from remote to local, only aggregated values pass through, is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAP HANA Smart Data Access (SDA)** provides you with the option to federate queries over multiple data sources and to access data stored in external databases (incl. external SAP HANA databases) by a query or a calculation model in SAP HANA.

In this scenario, your SAP HANA database acts as a database client to the external databases. This involved the transfer of queries and result sets between SAP HANA and the external databases and obviously also the materialisation of result sets - SAP HANA cannot reach into another database's memory and read internal data representation.

The "smart" bit in SDA is that the SAP HANA query processor is aware of the technical capabilities of the external data sources and creates queries accordingly. This includes choosing join strategies, filter push-downs and e.g. group by push-downs.
Whether or not any of these operations are actually done for a specific query depends on the capabilities of the data sources, the expected data volumes and on the specific query.

In practical terms, this means that you have to check how the actual execution looks like for all of your queries.